# Rails / postgresql Migrate Data from Database to Newly created database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, migration

I have an existing database on my server containing many tables with content. Now I have created a new database but some columns are added.

Is it possible to migrate all the data from the one database to the other.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your answer! But a more easy way is to dump the whole database like you said. But just transfer it to another server.

Like this:

```
To Dump:

pg_dump -U demo02 -h localhost -O demo02 > demo2.sql

To Restore:

psql -U demo3 demo3 < demo2.sql
```

Comment: This was very helpful, although a little confusing using the same text for the username and database name. `pg_dump -U ADMINUSER1 -h localhost -O DBASENAME > dump.sql` and `psql -U ADMINUSER2 DBASENAME < dump.sql`

Answer (score 2):

I've used the yaml_db gem to migrate DBs: https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db - this gem adds some rake tasks that are helpful

After installing the gem, you  can run `rake db:data:dump` to save your database to a .yml file.

Then, after changing your database configuration, you can run `rake db:data:load` to load the data into your new database.